# Как нажать на кнопку у которой отсутствует метод?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как нажать на кнопку у которой отсутствует метод, не используя при этом виртуальный браузер?

Допустим, успешно авторизовываемся в вконтакте используя `requests`, далее нам предлагают авторизовать приложение, разрешив доступ к необходимым настройкам, запрошенным при помощи параметра `scope` (в моем случае это `audio`)

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ид_вашего_приложения&scope=audio&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&v=5.30&response_type=token
```

Но у кнопки `Разрешить` в окне отсутствует метод. Как нажать на нее или узнать какой запрос с какими параметрами и куда нужно сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы узнать, что отправляет страница при нажатии на кнопку, можно воспользоваться средствами разработчика, доступными в браузере.

Напримет, для Google Chrome их можно открыть, выбрав в меню пункт More tools -> Developer tools, или нажав <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

У вас появится дополнительная панель в окне браузера. То, что вам необходимо, находится на вкладке Network.

Перейдите на нужную страницу с кнопкой. Введите все необходимые данные на странице. Очистите содержимое списка кнопкой Clear, чтобы после было проще искать конкретно ваш запрос.

Нажмите на интересующую вас кнопку. В этот момент в списке появится большое количество разных сообщений. Скорее всего, важная для вас информация будет располагаться в начале списка. Найдите там ваш запрос (с большой вероятностью, судя по описанию, он будет иметь тип POST в поле Method)

Когда выберете запрос, перейдите на вкладку Headers, вас интересуют Request Headers и Form Data (если запрос POST).

Comment: огромное спасибо, но как оказалось это GET запрос с некоторыми неизвестными параметрами, откуда их брать? или можно ли при запросе оставить значение этих параметров пустым? `/?act=grant_access&client_id=номер_приложения&settings=8192&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.vk.com%2Fblank.html&response_type=token&direct_hash=тут_цифры_с_буквами&token_type=0&v=5.30&state=&display=page&ip_h=тут_цифры_с_буквами&hash=тут_цифры_с_буквами&https=1

Comment: Вы можете попробовать найти эту информацию в коде самой страницы. Чаще всего, она там и находится. Иногда её можно найти в Coockie